How to import CSV in Laravel?
I want to make a CSV import using the maatwebsite/excel package. I have made the codes. And the data format that I want to import is as below:
Trans Date,Eff Date,Trans Description,Trans Code,Debit,Credit,Ledger Balance,User Id
1/6/24,1/6/24,"BRIVA18881020500WBNKAbdullah",6669/005,0.00,300000.00,15769068331.89,08881
1/6/24,1/6/24,"BRIVA188810222NBMBMOHAMAD",6669/005,0.00,6708334.00,15768068331.89,8888   

And here are the codes that I have created:
CheckingAccountController.php
public function import(Request $request)
{
    try {
        $request->validate([
            'file' => 'required',
        ]);

        $file = $request->input('file');
        $path = storage_path('tmp/uploads/' . $file);

        if (!file_exists($path)) {
            return back()->with('toast_errors', 'File not found.');
        }

        $import = Excel::import(new CheckingAccountReceiptImport, $path, null, \Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel::CSV);

        if (!$import) {
            return back()->with('toast_errors', 'File not imported.');
        }

        File::delete($path);

        return back()->with('toast_success', 'File imported successfully.');
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return back()->with('toast_errors', 'Ooops! Something went wrong.');
    }
}

CheckingAccountReceiptImport.php
<?php

namespace App\Imports;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use App\Models\RekeningKoran;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithBatchInserts;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithChunkReading;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithCustomCsvSettings;

class CheckingAccountReceiptImport implements ToCollection, WithHeadingRow, WithCustomCsvSettings, WithBatchInserts, WithChunkReading
{
    public function collection(Collection $rows)
    {
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            Log::info('Row: ' . json_encode($row));
            RekeningKoran::create([
                'trans_date' => $row[0] ? Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/y', $row[0])->format('Y-m-d') : null,
                'eff_date' => $row[1] ? Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/y', $row[1])->format('Y-m-d') : null,
                'trans_description' => $row[2],
                'trans_code' => $row[3],
                'debet' => $row[4] ? doubleval($row[4]) : 0,
                'kredit' => $row[5] ? doubleval($row[5]) : 0,
                'ledger_balance' => $row[6] ? doubleval($row[6]) : 0,
                'user' => $row[7],
            ]);
        }
    }

    public function headingRow(): int
    {
        return 10;
    }

    public function batchSize(): int
    {
        return 1000;
    }
    
    public function chunkSize(): int
    {
        return 1000;
    }

    public function getCsvSettings(): array
    {
        return [
            'delimiter' => ","
        ];
    }
}

With the codes above, the data from the imported CSV file could not be inserted into the table I wanted. And if I look at the laravel.log file, the data from the CSV file fails to read in the format I want. The following is the log recorded in the laravel.log file:
[2024-07-14 23:58:02] local.INFO: Row: {"1624":"1\/6\/24","briva18881020500wbnkabdullah":"BRIVA188810222NBMBMOHAMAD","6669005":"6669\/005","4":0,"300000":6708334,"1576135999789":15768068331.89,"0888122":"8888   "} 

What is the correct way to create a CSV import feature with my data format?

You can create a request and put a rule like: 'file' => 'mimes:csv' to ensure that files are a csv.
